# compute a value to a let struct property in init

Tags: swift, swift2

I have a swift struct named Product which takes a Dictionary in its init method. I want to compute a price `value` in a local Price struct within my Product. I want this value to be a `let` constant since it won't ever change, but swift won't allow me to do that without using `var`, saying that the `let` constant is not properly initialized.

How can I make my `value` property inside my Price struct a let constant in this case?

```
struct Product {
    let price: Price

    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let tmp = dictionary["price"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> { price = Price(dictionary: tmp) } else { price = Price() }
    }

    struct Price {
        var value = ""

        init() {
        }

        init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
            if let xForY = dictionary["xForY"] as? Array<Int> {
                if xForY.count == 2 {
                    value = "\(xForY[0]) for \(xForY[1])"
                }
            }
            if let xForPrice = dictionary["xForPrice"] as? Array<Int> {
                if value == "" && xForPrice.count == 2 {
                    value = "\(xForPrice[0]) / \(xForPrice[1]):-"
                }
            }
            if let reduced = dictionary["reduced"] as? String {
                if value == "" {
                    value = "\(reduced):-"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rewrite the code so that the compiler gets what you intend to do actually. It is not clever enough to deduce it from the way you coded it.

I would also suggest that you make the initializer for the `Price` struct failable instead of using an empty string for the `value` property. As a consequence of that change the `price` property of the `Product` struct becomes an optional.

```
struct Product {
    let price: Price?

    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        if let tmp = dictionary["price"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            price = Price(dictionary: tmp)
        }
        else {
            price = nil
        }
    }

    struct Price {
        let value : String

        init?(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
            if let xForY = dictionary["xForY"] as? Array<Int> where xForY.count == 2 {
                value = "\(xForY[0]) for \(xForY[1])"
            }
            else if let xForPrice = dictionary["xForPrice"] as? Array<Int> where xForPrice.count == 2 {
                value = "\(xForPrice[0]) / \(xForPrice[1]):-"
            }
            else if let reduced = dictionary["reduced"] as? String {
                value = "\(reduced):-"
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I liked the ```where``` keyword in the if let statement. I will probably avoid the struct being an optional since I know what value it should have as fallback, which is "". So I was missing the last lonely ```else```-case in own tries. Thank you @iOSX

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that (1) you're assigning to `value` in the declaration, (2) you're not assigning a value in `init()`, and (3) you're referencing and reassigning `value` in `init([String: AnyObject])`. You can only assign a value to a constant once and can only reference its value after its been assigned to.

To fix the issue, you can either make your property publicly readonly:

```
private(set) var value: String = ""
```

Or you can use a second variable inside your `init`:

```
struct Price {
    let value: String

    init() {
        self.value = ""
    }

    init(dictionary: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        var v: String = ""
        if let xForY = dictionary["xForY"] as? Array<Int> {
            if xForY.count == 2 {
                v = "\(xForY[0]) for \(xForY[1])"
            }
        }
        if let xForPrice = dictionary["xForPrice"] as? Array<Int> {
            if v == "" && xForPrice.count == 2 {
                v = "\(xForPrice[0]) / \(xForPrice[1]):-"
            }
        }
        if let reduced = dictionary["reduced"] as? String {
            if v == "" {
                v = "\(reduced):-"
            }
        }
        self.value = v
    }
}
```